Postgresql - create unique constraint on partioned table using existing unique index
I have a gigantic partitioned table (4.6 T) on PostgreSQL 15.
It has a unique index that was created manually (not using a constraint query).
Now, I would like to add the unique constraint to the table (which corresponds to my existing unique index).
Since recreating the constraint from scratch would be extremely long (because of the indexation phase), I am trying to find out if there is a way to create the constraint using the existing index.
I know, this feature is available on regular table but not on partitioned ones. However, maybe there is an expert trick to do so.
